# C#, Data parsing error with DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, parsing, exception, datetime, string-formatting

I have a string `Value = "12/11/2013"` and try to parse this using

```
DateTime.ParseExact(Value, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

But have an exception `FormatException` and cannot undestand why.

Comment: try `DateTime.ParseExact(Value, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Works for me. I am not getting any errors. What culture is the thread running with?

Comment: No error occurs.. its work fine for me...

Comment: *works on my machine* is not a good excuse. Code in the question is machine specific and will produce different results in different environments. `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` will make code to produce same results on different environments.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov - That's why I asked in my comment what culture is being used.

Comment: @Oded sorry, maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how it's relevant. He stated `FormatException` is thrown and he wanted to get rid of it. Also code that throws `FormatException` exception in one machine and works on another is not the best code one can imagine and in this situation probably should be avoided.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Sure. But you can't assume that `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is the right solution without knowing what problem the OP is trying to solve.

Comment: @Oded agree, that's sometimes the most hard part on SO. I just don't see how OPs remark, for example "I have `be-BY` as current culture", will help us to solve his problem

Comment: @IlyaIvanov - For me, at least, it would allow reproduction of the issue. From there, I could come up with a suitable solution (or ask OP for more info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(Value, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

To:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(Value, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: You should note, that passing `null` will take current culture

Answer (score 3):

From your profile it appears that you are under `be-By` [culture](http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/), and that is why you are getting the exception. The following code will produce the same exception.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("be-BY");
string Value = "12/11/2013";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Value, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

To comeover the exception use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` like:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Value, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(Value, "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy", null);
```